# How to change english to spanish language for a UILabel text

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, localization

In my application I want to change a `UILabel` text *english* to *spanish* language when clicking on a `UIButton`. I refer the below links :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring--mobile-11603

http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

I follow the procedure in the above links. It's working when i change the language in settings app. I don't want this. I need to change the label text *english* to *spanish* when clicking on a button.

Is this possible. If this is possible please help me. It's killing my time.

Answer (score 1):

Just my example, you need KEY_LANGUAGE to know which current language is used

```
NSString* NSCustomLocalizedString( NSString *key , NSString *comment)
{
NSString *rs = nil;
if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:KEY_LANGUAGE ] == e_language_japanese)
{
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-ja",nil);
}
else
{
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-en",nil);
}
return rs;
}
```

**Edit:**

- KEY_LANGUAGE: 0: Japanese ; 1: English
- I have two options: When user chooses English, I set this key to 1 and vice versa
- First launch app, I use Japanese as default I will set:`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: e_language_japanese forKey:KEY_LANGUAGE]`

  ```
  typedef enum{
   e_language_japanese,
   e_language_english
  }ENUM_LANGUAGE;
  ```

Comment: what is KEY_LANGUAGE and e_language_japanese here @nmh

Comment: how can i set e_language_japanese @nmh